# Graphical Tablet tip pressure not recognized by Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, drivers, graphics-tablet

So, I have [Graphic Tablet WP8060 from Trust](http://www.trust.com/en/product/16447-slimline-sketch-tablet). It is not so new model, but it fits my requirements. I managed to install drivers, and my Windows 10 see it:
[image]
[image]

However, Windows don't recognize tip pressure of the pen. I can't use it in Photoshop, or anywhere else. But it moves pointer, and works pretty much as mouse.

Maybe problem is deeper, because when I trying to "Practice using flicks", windows giving me error (You cannot use a mouse or finger to perform a flick. Try again using your tablet pen)
[image]
I used usb debugger and it showing tip pressure value:

[image]

It changes as It should with pen pressure:

[image]

Where can be problem, and how can I fix it? Maybe there are any universal driver, which can force Windows to recognize values received from USB device to interpretative as graphical tablet? Or any other solution?

Trying to contact tablet's vendor will not bring any luck — they use same driver, as all small companies, which produce WP8060 tablets under different names.

Comment: Can you please, provide the errors in a text form, unrelated to anything you have done imgur isn't currently working.  So we can't currently see your images.

Comment: Interesting... I know about imgur issue, so used different storage. Error text added, as you asked.

Comment: If you laid one of Microsoft's free Windows 7 VMs using Hyper-V or VirtualBox and you attach the device to the VM, does it work then?

Comment: I didn't try it yet. I don't have much experience with VirualBox. But I will try. What both results will mean?

Comment: Your question in your comment isn't clear

Comment: What will mean, if it will work in VirtualBox on Windows 7? And what will mean, if it will not work in VirtualBox on Windows 7?

Comment: Can't test, because VirtualBox (IntelHaxm exactly) giving me BSoD on host machine. Need to find solution without VB

Comment: So use Hyper-V I cannot tell you how to fix until I know the device works within a Hypervisor virtual machine.